# Input scope for textbox not working in windows 10 universal apps

Tags: c#, windows, textbox, windows-10, windows-10-universal

Here i tried the code.

Xaml:

```
<TextBox Header="Telephone Number" InputScope="TelephoneNumber"/>
```

Cs:

```
TextBox phoneNumberTextBox = new TextBox();
phoneNumberTextBox.Header="Telephone Number";    
InputScope scope = new InputScope();
InputScopeName scopeName = new InputScopeName();
scopeName.NameValue = InputScopeNameValue.TelephoneNumber;
scope.Names.Add(scopeName);
phoneNumberTextBox.InputScope = scope;
```

but when i press any key on keyboard it showing on textbox any one please help me for this..

Comment: @Manu Windows 10 Enterprise (Build 10240)

Comment: I mean the build verion try >> Windows Key + R, type “winver”  http://www.howtogeek.com/236195/how-to-find-out-which-build-and-version-of-windows-10-you-have/

Comment: @Manu Windows 10.0 Enterprise (Build 10240)

Comment: The InputScope in the TextBox is just a hint to the OS as to which keyboard should be displayed. It won't do any checking as to what kind of input it will accept. In order to accept only numbers you have to manually check the input key on the KeyDown or TextChanging events

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to restrict characters from Textbox Try to add Key_Down Event inside textbox.

`<TextBox Name="textbox" KeyDown="textbox_KeyDown" MaxLength="10"InputScope="Number" />`

and C# code

```
 private void textbox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((e.Key < VirtualKey.NumberPad0 || e.Key > VirtualKey.NumberPad9) & (e.Key < VirtualKey.Number0 || e.Key > VirtualKey.Number9))
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: This probably isn't the right way as it might only work for mobile! Better use Regex pattern

Comment: If it's not a numeric character, prevent the TextBox from handling the keystroke

Comment: Using KeyDown will work only when the input comes through the keyboard. It will still let through unrestricted characters through Cut & Paste, IMEs, Ink recognition, Speech input, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Read the document https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/hh702632

> The input scope provides a hint at the type of text input expected by
> the control. Various elements of the system can respond to the hint
> provided by the input scope and provide a specialized UI for the input
> type. For example, the touch keyboard might show a number pad for text
> input when the control has its InputScope set to Number.
>
> The control might also interpret the data being entered differently
> (typically for East Asian related input scopes). The input scope does
> not perform any validation, and does not prevent the user from
> providing any input through a hardware keyboard or other input device.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a my solution

```
<TextBox Name="texbox"   TextChanging="intTextBox_TextChanging" MaxLength="10" InputScope="Number" />


private void intTextBox_TextChanging(TextBox sender, TextBoxTextChangingEventArgs args)
{
    if (!Regex.IsMatch(sender.Text, "^\\d*?\\d*$") && sender.Text != "")
    {
        int pos = sender.SelectionStart - 1;
        sender.Text = sender.Text.Remove(pos, 1);
        sender.SelectionStart = pos;
    }
}
```